# Performance issue when offset used in SAQL

Tags: rest-api, rest, einstein-analytics, saql

I am using the endpoint **data/v35.0/wave/query** to execute a SAQL query.

When I execute the below SAQL which does not contain offset, I am getting the response approzimately in 1 secs

```
load \"xxxx/xxxx\"; q = group q by ('Name', 'NPI'); q = foreach q generate 'Name' as 'Name',  count() as 'count'; q = limit q 2000;
```

But when I execute the same query with offset it is almost taking 30 secs for a single query execution. Below is the query with offset

```
load \"xxxx/xxxx\"; q = group q by ('Name', 'NPI'); q = foreach q generate 'Name' as 'Name',  count() as 'count'; q = offset q 2000 ; q = limit q 2000;
```

Is there any issues with the way I am using the offset?

```
             -- OR --
```

Is it an issue in Salesforce Wave REST API?